# how to style HTML when using react-native-print

Tags: reactjs, native, react-native, react-native-ios

So what I am trying to print out html but with little styling i tried everything that i know of but I was't able to get it done.Every thing is working fine thought can't style the Html.I even tried to bind it with the style tag properties but still it didn't worked.

My code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  NativeModules,
  Platform,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';


import RNPrint from 'react-native-print';

export default class RNPrintExample extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedPrinter: null
  }

  // @NOTE iOS Only
  selectPrinter = async () => {
    const selectedPrinter = await RNPrint.selectPrinter()
    this.setState({ selectedPrinter })
  }

  // @NOTE iOS Only
  silentPrint = async () => {
    if (!this.state.selectedPrinter) {
      alert('Must Select Printer First')
    }

    const jobName = await RNPrint.print({
      printerURL: this.state.selectedPrinter.url,
      html: '<h1>Silent Print</h1>'
    })

  }
    //trying to style this HTML
  async printHTML() {
    await RNPrint.print({
      html: '<h1>Heading 1</h1><h2>Heading 2</h2><h3>Heading 3</h3>'
    })
  }


  async printRemotePDF() {
    await RNPrint.print({ filePath: 'https://graduateland.com/api/v2/users/jesper/cv' })
  }

  customOptions = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.selectedPrinter &&
          <View>
            <Text>{`Selected Printer Name: ${this.state.selectedPrinter.name}`}</Text>
            <Text>{`Selected Printer URI: ${this.state.selectedPrinter.url}`}</Text>
          </View>
        }
      <Button onPress={this.selectPrinter} title="Select Printer" />
      <Button onPress={this.silentPrint} title="Silent Print" />
    </View>

    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && this.customOptions()}
        <Button onPress={this.printHTML} title="Print HTML" />
        <Button onPress={this.printPDF} title="Print PDF" />
        <Button onPress={this.printRemotePDF} title="Print Remote PDF" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

Any help Would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .heading{
        background-color: red;
        }
        .block {
        background-color: black;
        height: 30;
        }
        .text{
        color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class='heading'>Title</h1>
    <div class='block'>
        <span class='text'>Hello, World !</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

I was able to style it by storing the above HTML inside back-ticks (``) and using it like

```
RNPrint.print({
  html: `<html>... ....</html>`
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as a guide. worked well for me.

```
<page size="A4"></page>
 <page size="A4"></page>
 <page size="A4" layout="landscape"></page>
  <page size="A5"></page>
  <page size="A5" layout="landscape"></page>
  <page size="A3"></page>
  <page size="A3" layout="landscape"></page>
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}
page[size="A4"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 21cm;  
}
page[size="A3"] {
  width: 29.7cm;
  height: 42cm;
}
page[size="A3"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 42cm;
  height: 29.7cm;  
}
page[size="A5"] {
  width: 14.8cm;
  height: 21cm;
}
page[size="A5"][layout="landscape"] {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 14.8cm;  
}
@media print {
  body, page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/LFAes